# Which one should I buy DDR3 OR DDR3L

Tags: memory, ddr3

I want to add another ram to my laptop  , Most websites including Crucial.com, recommend that I need to buy a ddr3l RAM.

But it's weird when I opened my laptop, on the RAM slot was written : ddr3 1.5 v.

so Which one should I buy ddr3 or ddr3l If I buy a ddr3l RAM will it damage my laptop or vice versa ddr3 will it damage my laptop?

my current ram is :ELPIDA J4208EFBG-GNL-F 4g
and my intel processor :intel cori5- 4200u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see on  ELPIDA J4208EFBG-GNL-F datasheet, your current RAM is backward compatible for 1.5V :

```
Power supply: 1.35V (typ)
ó  VDD = 1.283V to 1.45V
ó  Backward compatible for VDD, VDDQ = 1.5V ± 0.075V
```

Take a good look at your mother board datasheet. It may not be for DDR3L.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so my current ram is 1.35 v which means my motherboard can support DDR3L? or should I take a look at datasheet I am asking because my English is not so good I can't get head around datasheet.

Comment: No, your mother board could be 1.5V, and it compatible with your RAM.